# Cannot cast from int to MyClass

Tags: java

I have a problem in dealing with the conversion of integer to string. This is my code :

```
MyClass getRow;
getRow = (MyClass) getListAdapter().getCount();
```

I found an error on this line: `Cannot cast from int to MyClass`

This is my MyClass ListView Adapter :

```
public String toString() {
    return myclass;
}
```

**Solved**

I have found a solution by adding a few tricks to convert an integer to a string, like this :

```
int i ;
i = getListAdapter().getCount();
String str = String.valueOf(i);
TextView totalRow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalRow);
totalRow.setText(str);
```

thanks for all of your answers, awesome Stackoverflow !

Comment: getRow is a class object. getCount returns an integer. You are casting an INT into a class object. In simple language ,you are trying to force a dog to be a cat. Think yourself. is it possible ?

Comment: @RahulGupta well, thank you guys!
I also thought like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is a primitive and not a class, so the compiler is correct. Why do you expect that an `int` transform magically into `MyClass`? What are you trying to do here?

If I understand you correct, you must assing the value of `getRow()` to your class somehow (either via a setter, by constructor or by accessing the member) and then you can use `MyClass`. Of course if you want to convert the `int` to a String object, you have to convert it:

```
String s = String.valueof(integervalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast an `int` to an `Object`. In the first row you mention you are exactly doing that. `getCount()` returns an `int` and you try to cast it to (MyClass).

You never cast primitives to objects in java.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot cast this.  However, you can achieve a similar effect if you create a constructor for MyClass which accepts an integer as input.  So something like:

```
public MyClass(int x) {
   // do stuff to convert as you see fit here
}
```

then when using it, you do:

```
getRow = new MyClass( getListAdapter().getCount());
```